# How to delete all rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete *all* the rows in a dataframe.

The reason I want to do this is so that I can reconstruct the dataframe with an iterative loop. I want to start with a completely empty dataframe.

Alternatively, I could create an empty df from just the column / type information if that is possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The latter is possible and strongly recommended - "inserting" rows row-by-row is highly inefficient. A sketch could be

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> index = np.arange(0, 10)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, columns=['foo', 'bar'])
>>> df
Out[268]: 
   foo  bar
0  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN
6  NaN  NaN
7  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 117):

Here's another method if you have an existing DataFrame that you'd like to empty without recreating the column information:

```
df_empty = df[0:0]
```

`df_empty` is a DataFrame with zero rows but with the same column structure as `df`

Answer (score 11):

You can also use [`head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
df_empty = df.head(0)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have an existing DataFrame with the columns you want then extract the column names into a list comprehension then create an empty DataFrame with your column names.

```
# Creating DataFrame from a CSV file with desired headers
csv_a = "path/to/my.csv"
df_a = pd.read_csv(csv_a)

# Extract column names into a list
names = [x for x in df_a.columns]

# Create empty DataFrame with those column names
df_b = pd.DataFrame(columns=names)
```

Comment: I think this won't include the column type info

Answer (score 6):

```
df.drop(df.index,inplace=True)
```

This line will delete all rows, while keeping the column names.

Comment: it's actually a good method when you don't want to actually recreate the variable, which can be problematic if you are doing that inside a function and want to avoid UnboundLocalError

Answer (score 0):

Old Thread. But i found another way

```
df_final=df_dup[0:0].copy(deep=True)
```